# Circular dependencies in Dojo cause stack overflow issue when trying to pack them with r.js

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, amd, r.js

My project contains some legacy Dojo code under the hood. And unfortunately, some of these Dojo modules use circular dependencies.

To be more specific, `dojo/dom-construct` depends on `dojo/dom-attr`,  which depends on `dojo/dom-prop`, which depends on `dojo/dom-construct`.

This causes a stack overflow when using r.js to pack it :

```
{ Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
In module tree:
    symbology/main
      luciad/symbology/SymbologyProvider
        luciad/symbology/JsonSymbologyParser
          luciad/symbology/MS2525Symbology
            luciad/symbology/HierarchicalSymbology
              luciad/symbology/DelegatingLabelCanvasUtil
                luciad/view/style/DelegatingLabelCanvas
                  luciad/view/style/HTML5LabelCanvas
                    luciad/view/style/DrawAsyncPointLabelHtmlContents
                      luciad/view/style/StyleUtil
                        luciad/view/style/SimpleStrokeStyle
                          luciad/view/style/HTML5DrawStrokeCommandMixin
                            luciad/view/style/HTML5CanvasUtil
                              luciad/dojo/dom-construct
                                luciad/dojo/dom-attr
                                  luciad/dojo/dom-prop
                                    luciad/dojo/dom-construct
                                      luciad/dojo/dom-attr
                                        luciad/dojo/dom-prop
                                          luciad/dojo/dom-construct
                                            luciad/dojo/dom-attr
                                              luciad/dojo/dom-prop
                                                luciad/dojo/dom-construct
                                                  luciad/dojo/dom-attr
                                                    luciad/dojo/dom-prop
                                                      luciad/dojo/dom-construct
                                                        luciad/dojo/dom-attr
                                                          luciad/dojo/dom-prop
                                                            luciad/dojo/dom-construct
                                                              luciad/dojo/dom-attr
                                                                  ...
```

How can I get around this without modifying the code of these Dojo modules?